# A way\design to develop multiple version of java spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, versioning

Need a way\design to develop multiple version of java spring rest api for example:
exampleAPiV1,exampleAPiV2,exampleAPiV3

all 3 api version's should be live at the same time. Also if there is need for bug fix\enhancement in a particular version, the changes do not impact other version with Zero or minimum  code duplication.

Comment: Why do you need multiple versions, typically you can do a lot of mutations to an API and maintain backwards compatibility. You often see the API version in the URL,  /v1/exampleapi/sayhello, you then use an adapter to upgrade older messages to the newest version, to avoid code douplication. Another possibility I have seen is to have one endpoint and include a version header.

Comment: We have multiple clients to our api. Not all of them agree too move to new version. I want that at any point of time we can support any version without breaking or impacting existing functionality. Versioning through header or url is fine but i am looking for a solution that helps me maintain code behind the api's with minimum duplication.

Comment: Most of the time you try to upgrade the older messages to the newest version. I have done something similar with an internal setting protocol, which changed for every release, and sometimes even in hotfixes, so the server had to be able to talk to 5+ different client versions. The trick is to have simple converter which can upgrade only to the next version. When the client says he wants to talk version 3, you convert your version 5 message down to 4, then to 3 and upgrade from 3 to 5 when receiving. This way adding an extra version only requires converter from the previous to current version.

Answer (score 1):

For API versioning there are 3 ways:

1. expose API version in the URL example:

   http://api.example.com/**v1**/examples

   http://api.example.com/**v2**/examples
2. Using Accept Header, Accept: application/json+**v1**
3. Using custom header, X-Api-Version: 1

Regarding to the code, you may use the routes/headers in order to execute the corresponding functionality.

I mean in certain point of your application(middle-wares) or before actions you can get the version value from the URL or from the header and based on the value you call the functionality.